# How do I stop dynamic web controls from firing page_load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-lists

I have accumulated an ASP.NET project that was running everything off of one page with no post back functionality. The core of the site uses a Silverlight application that we are trying to dispose of.

I am trying to dynamically create list items using the following code.

```
void AddLinkButton(string id, string text) {
        LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
        link.ID = id;
        link.Text = text;
        link.Click += new EventHandler(link_Click);
        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        li.Controls.Add(link);
        tabsNav.Controls.Add(link);
    }
```

This all works fine and dandy. However, when the link is clicked, it is running the page_load all over again and then its running the click event. How do I stop the page_load from reloading everything and only update the content that I am wishing to refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Page_Load` is a part of the Standard `ASP.NET Page lifecycle` for Postbacks & callbacks, and the behavior you are encountering is expected.

In order for you not to create the button on Postback is to have a code similar to

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack && !IsCallback)
        AddLinkButton("abc", "abc");
}
```

This only adds the LinkButton to the Page Controls when the User Requests the Page for the First time, but not subsequently.

Comment: I see. That answers my question. I mostly do backend development so the web stuff is taking some time to get used to.

Answer (score 2):

Most commonly we wrap the content we don't want to execute in the page load with a !IsPostBack if statement.

i.e.

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Do actual page load stuff
    }
}
```